# What is the word for an independent-minded person? What is the opposite of that word?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I'm looking for two words: a word that means an independent-minded person and its opposite. Not necessarily a rebel or someone who wants to stand out, but someone who is comfortable sticking with what he prefers and doesn't get swayed by other people.

Word #1

For example, let's say someone is out with his friends and his friends decide to order a beer, but he doesn't order one because he doesn't drink and he is not anxious about trying to fit it with everyone.

Word #2

And the opposite scenario in which someone, who doesn't drink and actually doesn't like drinking, only does it when he is out with his friends because he wants to fit in with everyone and be accepted by them.

What would the words be for both cases? I have found words for the first case  through google translate, but I am not sure which one to use.

独立した

非適合主義者

個人主義者

Can you please provide example sentences for both the opposite words as well so I know how to use it?

Comment: For one-word translations, I would recommend ALC instead: https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=independent-minded&ref=sa

Comment: @Earthliŋ Thank you and what you would recommend for looking up sentences? jisho.org, tangorin and tatoeba returned no results for 独立心.

Comment: @rgb_jewel I use ejje.weblio.jp for example sentences. https://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E7%8B%AC%E7%AB%8B%E5%BF%83

Answer (score 2):

After looking at your rather mundane example, the first phrase that came to my mind was 周りに流されない人. Its antonym is (周りに)[流されやすい人](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E6%B5%81%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%84%E3%81%99%E3%81%84&ref=sa), who is someone easily influenced by others.

個人主義者 ("individualist") is not entirely wrong, but it's probably too strong in this context. Not ordering a beer is not really "individualistic" to me. 非適合主義者 is not an established phrase and I have almost no idea what it could possibly mean. 独立した人 refers to a person who is financially or psychologically independent, but again, it's too strong. A person who does not order a beer will not qualify as an independent person.